# importing global css to VueJs does not load css to app bundle

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I imported the semantic-ui css to the top Vue component in my app(App.vue) as the following

```
<style>
    @import '/assets/css/semantic.rtl.min.css';
</style>
```

but the Css is not available and not applied 
I am well aware that I could import CSS files in index.html but I wanted to load it in the app so it got compile in to one file along other files.
in general what is the best way for importing global static CSS files to VueJs?
should I do some more configuration for properly loading the CSS files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import the CSS file in `main.js`. See the example below:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import './assets/css/semantic.rtl.min.css';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

In build time your CSS file will be processed.

Comment: thanks,your solution definitely is the correct answer to the question in title, but for me beside the import problem there was a problem with semantic-ui build also, so I rebuild it based on solution on this link and now importing it the way you described above works fine